# nullPointerException Handler Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, handler

I got a nullPointerException on getHandler, and I can't solve this problem..

Can you help me? I have no idea where is the bug.. the error occurs randomly on the same situation.

some code...

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                    mProgressStatus = Elabora();
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar1.setProgress((int) mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
            if(isStopped)
            {
                op_ko.show();
                     //error in the next line
            txt_status1.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        txt_status1.setText(R.string.op_ko);
                    }
                });

            }
                else
                {
                    op_ok.show();
                    txt_status1.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            txt_status1.setText(R.string.op_ok);
                        }
                    });
                }
            btn_stop.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    btn_stop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });         
        }
```

Comment: Please post full LogCat output.

Comment: And show where in the code you are setting the handler for txt_status1. The most direct possibility is that you never set a handler!

Comment: here is the logCat: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47137048/logcat.txt

Comment: setting the handler for txt_status1? yeah, I guess i have not set any handler...or maybe i don't understand.. what you mean by setting the handler?

Comment: The logcat tells you the Null Pointer Exception occurs in frm_elabora.java, line 136. How about telling us which line that is?

Comment: line 136 --> txt_status1.getHandler().post(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {txt_status1.setText(R.string.op_ok);}});

Comment: Ok, so txt_status1 is or becomes null. Now show us where and how you initialize txt_status1, and also tell where (in what method/event) you are calling the code you posted above.

Comment: final TextView txt_status1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status1);

Comment: this is the code cleaned to view where i calling handler
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47137048/code.txt

Comment: Check whether `txt_status1` is null right after that line. If it is, then `findViewById()` couldn't find `R.id.txt_status1`. Check that you called `setContentView()` beforehand, and that `R.id.txt_status1` is actually in that layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of variables in there that could be null, please try to use debugging to figure out which line it is (i.e. read the logcat or rerun with a `Java Exception Breakpoint` on `NullPointerException`).

If the error occurs or doesn't occur "randomly", one of the usual pitfalls is initializing member variables (mHandler ... but herhaps also txt_status1, progressBar1, btn_stop, etc?) outside of the onCreate of an Activity. If Android initializes an orientation change, or randomly decides to kill and recreate your activity for any other reason, you'll lose state and all those member variables will be null.

Comment: hi paul-jan...thank you for answerin... i ask you if you can take a look to this.. frm_elabora.java 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47137048/frm_elabora.java
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: i think i solve the problem: i don't get NullPointerException anymore..i initialize handler out of onCreate and before new Trhead...  but yes, if Android initializes an orientation change.. some stuff like toast and other stuff restart...